# How do I make a Box2D wrap around world?

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I want to make a wrap around game effect where an object would go off the screen from the x-axis one side and reappear in a new y-axis position on the other side of the screen. The width is 250 pixels, so basically it would pass (0, y1) and would reappear at (300, y2).

```
    a.applyForceToCenter(aMovement, true);
    a.applyTorque(3000, true);

    FixtureDef fDef = new FixtureDef();
    BodyDef ballD = new BodyDef();

    ballD.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;

    //random location for asteroid
    int aLoc = (int) (aLocation * 15);
    float x = 300;
    switch(aLoc)
    {
    case 0:
        ballD.position.set(x, -105);
        break;
    case 1:
        ballD.position.set(x, -95);
        break;
    case 2:
        ballD.position.set(x, -80);
        break;
    case 3:
        ballD.position.set(x, -65);
        break;
    case 4:
        ballD.position.set(x, -50);
        break;
    case 5:
        ballD.position.set(x, -35);
        break;
    case 6:
        ballD.position.set(x, -20);
        break;
    case 7:
        ballD.position.set(x, -5);
        break;
    case 8:
        ballD.position.set(x, 10);
        break;
    case 9:
        ballD.position.set(x, 25);
        break;
    case 10:
        ballD.position.set(x, 40);
        break;
    case 11:
        ballD.position.set(x, 55);
        break;
    case 12:
        ballD.position.set(x, 70);
        break;
    case 13:
        ballD.position.set(x, 85);
        break;
    default:
        ballD.position.set(x, 0);
    }

    PolygonShape asteroid = new PolygonShape();
    asteroid.setAsBox(12.5f, 12.5f);

    //asteroid definition
    fDef.shape = asteroid;
    fDef.density = .5f;
    fDef.friction = .25f;
    fDef.restitution = .75f;

    a = world.createBody(ballD);
    a.createFixture(fDef);
    a.setFixedRotation(false);

   //asteroid image
    aSprite = new Sprite(new Texture("img/asteroid-icon.png"));
    aSprite.setSize(12.5f * 4, 12.5f * 4);
    aSprite.setOrigin(aSprite.getWidth() / 2, aSprite.getHeight() / 2);
    a.setUserData(aSprite);
    asteroid.dispose();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the setTransform() method on the ball if it leaves the screen on one side.
Basically, after each simulation step you'd check if the ball has been moved out on one side, then setTransform() with the new position and rotation.

Comment: Are you getting any error? When are you trying to set the transformation?

Comment: Well first, how do I retrieve the location of my body so when it reaches (0, 0) for example, I could then move it to (200, 0)

Comment: well after every simulation step you can access the bodies from the world. In the "Sprites and Bodies" section it shows how to iterate over your bodies: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/box2d#wiki-sprites-and-bodies ... you of course could also just store a reference to your ball. As seen in the example you can get the position of a body or the angle of its rotation (Note Box2d uses radians, libgdx degrees). Using this method you can check if it has reached or passed a location (left the screen) and then use setTransform(new Vector2(200,0), b.getAngle()); to move it.

Comment: Ok so now how do I make it detect its location repeatedly? I have the setTransform() part down

Comment: Well in your render() loop you are calling world.step(...), which does a simulation step. After that step() function you can just add your own handleScreenDeparture() method, where you check if(b.getPosition().x <=0) b.setTransform(300,b.getPosition().y, b.getAngle());

Or however you like... :) This way, every time the ball is leaving the screen on the left (assuming x=0 is at the left edge), it will be moved to the right side of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to use a mod operator on your x and y positions.  The idea being that you could mod whatever your x position and y position are with the pixel value of your box.  That way when your x value = maxWidth, it becomes zero, and same for the y value.