# Wrap around edge of world with specific customization

Tags: c++, box2d

i've been looking around to find the best way to have wrap arround edges of a world for the bodies.
I managed to use this topic to do it :
[How do I make a Box2D wrap around world?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236535/how-do-i-make-a-box2d-wrap-around-world)
Using SetTransform() i could make it appear on the other X/Z side.

Now Let's say i have an object for example a simple box 10x10.
If half the box goes beyond upper Y edge i want the portion that goes beyond to appear below with the other part of the box that is still visibile on the upper part to stay there.
To summarize i want a "real wrap arround edge like this used to be done in old games.
I hope i was clear enough...

Edit : 
I've added a picture to explain what i mean :
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i googled a bit found this article on Unity :

http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/create-an-asteroids-like-screen-wrapping-effect-with-unity--gamedev-15055

On Box2D I created 8 ghosts bodies which were positionned as defined in the article.

During Box2D Steps i added some logics to check where my original body is positionned. 
When it goes to the edges the Ghost Body appears on the other edge. It works also when the original Body goes on a corder. 4 ghosts bodies will appear on each edges.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Box2d but I have resolved this problem before in Processing, hopefully the logic translates easily

In Processing a rectangle is drawn as `rect(x, y, rectangleWidth, rectangleHeight)` at position `x`, `y` which represents the top left corner of the rectangle. The rectangle's width and height point right and down from `x` and `y` respectively

The idea is to draw the rectangle normally unless the bottom would be off the bottom edge of the viewport (because the rectangle's height points down based on `y`). If the rectangle is off the bottom edge of the viewport then you instead draw two partial rectangles

In the code below `height` is the height of your viewport

```
if (y < height-10)
  rect(x, y, 10, 10); // Normal condition, entire rectangle
else {
  rect(x, 0, 10, 10-(height-y)); // Top partial rectangle
  rect(x, y, 10, height-y); // Bottom partial rectangle
}
```

Comment: Simple and great idea. But gets quite difficult to handle custom draw for one "body" in Box2D. In fact someone pointed me out to use 2 box2d "bodies" and handle the display your way which seems better